# Prop not Reactive using VUE to send configuration

Tags: vue.js

I have started learning Vue and came quite far :) but still consider myself beginner. I have bought a vue based single page application template 
[Themeforest Template Link](https://themeforest.net/item/cover-dashboard-ui-kit-for-modern-web-application/19869018)

I am building my application over it and it uses [FlatPickr](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr)

I am trying to use FlatPickr's enable functionality

```
{
enable: ["2025-03-30", "2025-05-21", "2025-06-08", new Date(2025, 8, 9) ]
}
```

I asked the developer how to use this as it was not in instructions so he replied:

> you can use the `config` prop to pass all Flatpickr options.

I have codes which looks like this

```
 <c-flatpickr 
    v-validate="'required'"
    v-model="dateRange"
    :config="enabledDates"
    name="Select Date Range"
    value="" range
  />

enabledDates: function (){

  var data = this.trip.tripsDetails;          
  var options = {
    enable: [],
  };

  for (let i in data){

    options.enable.push(data[i].startingDate);

  }

    return options;

},
```

my problem is if I pass the data statically it works so if I put values in array manually like

```
var options = {
  enable: ['01-06-2018', '03-06-2018', '06-06-2018'],
};
```

it works but if I try to push values dynamically (as per my codes above) it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

// Here are the codes

```
data() {
      return {


        trip: new Form({

          //All Trips
          tripsDetails: [],

        }),

        dateRange: undefined,

      }
    },

methods: {

        getData(pageid){

          this.trip.tripsDetails = [];

          axios
            .get('/trip/getTrips',{

              params: {

                equipment_id : this.trip.equipment_id,
                dispatch_id: this.pageid

              }

            })

            .then(response => {

                this.trip.tripsDetails = response.data.data;

                this.loading();

            }).catch(error => {

                this.loading();

                this.errortoast();

            });

        },
```

Comment: Where on your vue isntance do you put the enabledDates function? Is it a method, a computed property or what else?

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann it's a computed property but I tried as a method too

Comment: Event hough you could shorten that method to a almost a single line I don't see why it wouldn't work with vue's reactivity, unless your data formats are not what the options expect. There is something that looks a bit smelly to me though: You are assigning `var data` to something you call tripDetails and then looping over that, trying to access startingDate. What's inside tripsDetails? Are you sure that this is an array? Can you provide more of your component's code? I'd guess the error is not in your provided code.

Comment: It is an array coming from data base and assigning to tripDetails. I have a chrome vue plugins and it shows that array options.enable has an array with values. Basically when page loads it gives an empty array because tripDetails is empty then axios request get a data and set as tripDetails. Then options.enable has an array.

Comment: Are you assigning `this.trip`to what's coming from axios? In this case `tripsDetails` is undefined in your initial render and will throw an error. I can only guess at this point, the code of the entire component would be helpful.

Comment: no I am assigning to this.trip.tripDetails it does have a data and displays on page. That part is working fine. Can I share my bitbucket with you so you can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173209/discussion-between-zee-and-philip-feldmann).

Comment: I added more codes in there now.